# python queue reading same data

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python socket server/client implementation. The server reads the data from the queue and pushes the data to the client.

The client reads and displays it. When I run this code the client always displays only the first 10 times in the queue. also everytime the same 10 times are being sent to the client.

Here is my data in the client.

```
 Client2 received data:  "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]["test-msg---0", "test-msg---1", "test-msg---2", "test-msg---3", "test-msg---4", "test-msg---5", "test-msg---6", "test-msg---7", "test-msg---8", "test-msg---9"]
```

Server code:-

```
# server2.py
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import Queue
import json

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

q = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(50000):
    print 'put data'
    q.put("test-msg---" + str(i))

def queue_get_all(q):
    items = []
    maxItemsToRetreive = 10
    for numOfItemsRetrieved in range(0, maxItemsToRetreive):
        try:
            if numOfItemsRetrieved == maxItemsToRetreive:
                break
            items.append(q.get_nowait())
        except Empty, e:
            print 'Queue empty'
    return items

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
        # filename='mytext.txt'
        # f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            # l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            l = queue_get_all(q)
            while (l):
                self.sock.sendall(json.dumps(l))
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                # l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print "Waiting for incoming connections..."
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Client code

```
# Python TCP Client A
import socket 

host = socket.gethostname() 
host = 'localhost'
port = 9999
BUFFER_SIZE = 2000 
MESSAGE = raw_input("tcpClientA: Enter message/ Enter exit:") 

tcpClientA = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
tcpClientA.connect((host, port))

while MESSAGE != 'exit':
    # tcpClientA.send(MESSAGE)     
    data = tcpClientA.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print " Client2 received data:", data
    MESSAGE = raw_input("tcpClientA: Enter message to continue/ Enter exit:")

tcpClientA.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `run`, you call `l = queue_get_all(q)` then you enter a loop with condition `while (l)`. Then you never reset `l`. So it begins true (i.e. non-empty list always evaluates to boolean true) and stays true forever. Probably you meant to call `queue_get_all` again inside the loop.

I'd also mention that after that loop, you have an `if not l` that is superfluous since the above loop will *only* exit when `l` is false.